# Is the speed of a PostgreSQL SELECT adversely affected by too many indexes on the table?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have read that when having a lot of indexes on a database It can seriously hurt the performance but in the PostgreSQL doc I can't find anything about it.

I have a very big table with something like 100 columns and a billion rows and often I have to do a lot of searches in a lot of different fields.

Does the performance of the PostgreSQL table will drop if I add a lot of indexes (maybe 10 unique column indexes and 5 or 7 3 column indexes)?

EDIT: With performance drop I mean the performance in fetching rows (select), the database will be updated once a month so the update and insert time are not an issue.

Comment: In theory the performance of write actions to any RDBMSs tables will drop as on each write the indexes need to be maintained. In this instance I would not take the lack of a note in documentation to mean there is no performance trade-off, there always is. As always, profile your application/database to see the exact cost of this trade-off.

Comment: [Everything you can possibly want to know about SQL indexes](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)

Comment: The database will be updated once a month or something like that, so the insert or update performance is not very important

Comment: @Topo In that case your trade-off is very heavily in favour of select performance, meaning indexes on items that participate in the where clause could prove beneficial.

Comment: @Topo what are those updates do?  If they affect lots of indexes and rows, maintaining indexes can easily run for hours.

Comment: @dezso Once a month the database will grow like 10 to 25 percent and only a column will be updated, but it won't be so bad if I drop the indexes, make this changes and then re-index the database.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth So the only trade of of having lots of indexes are space and update/insert time?

Comment: @Topo I can't say if they are the *only* trade-offs, but they are the most common. Not forgetting delete actions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The indexes are maintained when the content of the table has been modified (i.e. `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`)

The query planner of PostgreSQL can decide when to use an index and when it's not needed and a sequential scan is more optimal.

So having too many indexes will hurt the modifying performance, not the fetching.

Comment: So the only trade-of of having lots of indexes are space and update/insert time?

Comment: @Topo  Basically yes.  I wouldn't expect the planner getting confused by too many indexes :)

Comment: Yes, unnecessary indexes won't be used by the query planner.

Answer (score 2):

The indexes will have to be updated at each `insert` and `update` involving those columns.

Answer (score 1):

I have some charts about that on my site: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml

> An index is pure redundancy. It contains only data that is also stored
> in the table. During write operations, the database must keep those
> redundancies consistent. Specifically, it means that insert, delete
> and update not only affect the table but also the indexes that hold a
> copy of the affected data.

The chapter titles suggest the impact that indexes can have:

> Insert — cannot take direct benefit from indexes
>
> Delete — uses indexes for the where clause
>
> Update — does not affect all indexes of the table

Comment: It would be much more useful if you were to post the key portion of the content here, with a link back to your (disclaimed) site for more information.